# WPF DataGrid: how to show object with double values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an object like this:

```
public class MChiStructure
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    public double chiV1Plus;
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    public double chiV1Minus;
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    public double mV1Plus;
...
}
```

and I would like to have a DataGrid that shows, in first column, the variable names and, in second column, the double values.
I also would like to know if there is the possibility to hide some of the values (for example, if one is negative it must be hidden)

Thanks all

Comment: are you sure that you want DataGrid? in my view it is better to use ListView? Why do you choose DataGrid?

Comment: how do you use the ListView? post an answer with your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it it is code behind application, at first yo should create a model class and populate it code-behind. That's all. Please, see an example:

**Model:**

```
public class MChiStructure
{
    public string TitleField { get; set; }

    public double chiV1Plus { get; set; }

    public double chiV1Minus { get; set; }         

    public double mV1Plus { get; set; }
}
```

**Code-behind of the Window:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FillDataGrid();
}

private void FillDataGrid()
{
   ObservableCollection<MChiStructure> coll = new ObservableCollection<MChiStructure>();
   for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
   {
      coll.Add(new MChiStructure(){TitleField="Title " + start.ToString(), 
      chiV1Minus=start-1, chiV1Plus=start+1, mV1Plus=start-1});                                
   }
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = coll;       
}
```

**And XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
```

**Update. Using ListView:**

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="chiV1Plus:" Margin="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding chiV1Plus}" Margin="2"  />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="chiV1Minus:" Margin="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding chiV1Minus}" Margin="2" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="mV1Plus:" Margin="2" FontWeight="Bold" />
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding mV1Plus}" Margin="2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C# in code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   FillListView();
}

private void FillListView()
{
   List<MChiStructure> coll = new List<MChiStructure>();
   for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
   {
      coll.Add(new MChiStructure()
      {
          TitleField = "Your Title: " + start.ToString(),
          chiV1Minus = start - 1,
          chiV1Plus = start + 1,
          mV1Plus = start - 1
      });
   }
   listView.ItemsSource = coll;
}
```

Model:

```
public class MChiStructure
{
    public string TitleField { get; set; }

    public double chiV1Plus { get; set; }

    public double chiV1Minus { get; set; }

    public double mV1Plus { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: does this solution show the variable name and its value into the grid? It seems that it shows only TitleField and all the values...I need that each value has its name shown

Comment: it is not exactly what I need. I would like to see rows like the following: chiv1plus 1; chiv2plus 0; chiv3plus 2; ...so each row must have the name of the object field in first cell and the value of the field in second cell